# awk to take average of values in column 2 with reference to name in column1

Tags: bash, awk

```
RAM,80  
GAM,20  
DAM,30  
RAM,40  
DAM,20  
GAM,30
```

How to use awk to show average value of RAM, GAM and DAM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1]+=$2; ++b[$1]} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]/b[i], "("b[i]" values)"}' file
DAM 25 (2 values)
GAM 25 (2 values)
RAM 60 (2 values)
```

#### Explanation

`{a[$1]+=$2; ++b[$1]}`

- Store the z values (2nd column) in the array `a`.
- Store the amount of elements for each x value (1st column) in the array `b`.

`END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]/b[i]}'`

- Print the result looping through the values stored in the array.